# Is there a way to attach a character label with a sorted array output?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, char, integer

I have to create a vowel counter and sorter, where someone can input a word or phrase and the program picks out, counts, and sorts the vowels. I have the code to where it counts and sorts the variables and shows their counts to the user, but it doesn't say which vowel has which count and I have exhausted all of my resources. I am very new to coding and know very little, so if there's anything anyone can do to help, I would appreciate it endlessly.

```
int[] vowelcounter = {a, e, i, o, u}; //This is the count of the vowels after reading the input.
   boolean hasswapped = true;
    while(hasswapped)
    {
        hasswapped = false;
        for(int j = 0; j<vowelcounter.length; j++)  
            {
            for(int k = j+1; k<vowelcounter.length; k++)
                {
                    if(vowelcounter[j] > vowelcounter[k])
                    {
                        int temp = vowelcounter[j];
                        vowelcounter[j] = vowelcounter[j+1];
                        vowelcounter[j+1] = temp;
                        hasswapped = true;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
        
        for(int j=0; j<vowelcounter.length; j++)
            {   
                    System.out.println(vowelcounter[j]);
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure `[j+1]` should not be `[k]`?   Work through the case where the counters are 3, 2, 1, 4, 4,   On the first pass through the inner loop, we swap 3 and 2.  On the second pass, we swap 2 and 3 back again.

Comment: You're totally right, I didn't see that lol, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `int` value to represent a counter, a class may be introduced to store and print both the vowel character and its count:

```
class VowelCount {
    private final char vowel;
    private int count = 0;

    public VowelCount(char v) {
        this.vowel = v;
    }

    public void add() { this.count++; }

    public int getCount()  { return this.count; }

    public char getVowel() { return this.vowel; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return "Vowel '" + vowel + "' count = " + count;}
}
```

Then instead of `int[] count` an array of `VowelCount` is created and sorted:

```java
VowelCount[] vowelcounter = {
    new VowelCount('a'), new VowelCount('e'), new VowelCount('i'), 
    new VowelCount('o'), new VowelCount('u')
};
```

Sorting may be implemented using standard method `Arrays::sort` with a custom comparator instead of home-made bubble sorting

```
Arrays.sort(vowelcounter, Comparator.comparingInt(VowelCount::getCount));
```

Then printing of the stats is as follows (using `for-each` loop along with the overriden `toString`):

```java
for (VowelCount v: vowelcounter) {
    System.out.println(v); // print sorted by count
}
```

---

More advanced ways of calculating the frequencies is to use a map of vowels to their frequencies and sort the map by counter value.

Comment: Thank you!! I have to use bubble sorting as a requirement from my teacher sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something that is called HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> vowelCounts = new HashMap<>();
```

To add data to it just do:

```
vowelCounts.put("a", 1); // The vowel "a" is once in the sentence
vowelCounts.put("e", 2); // The vowel "e" is 2 times in the sentence
```

To print to the console:

```
for(String vowel : vowelCounts.keySet() ) {
     System.out.println(vowel + ": " + vowelCounts.get(vowel));
}
```

For more info: [click me!](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp)

Comment: But he wants the counters to be ordered by count.  HashMaps have no useful order.

Answer (score 0):

Have a `char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' }`.  Every time you swap the counters, make an identical swap in the vowels array.

```
int temp = vowelcounter[j];
vowelcounter[j] = vowelcounter[j+1];
vowelcounter[j+1] = temp;
char temp2 = vowel[j];
vowel[j] = vowel[j+1];
vowel[j+1] = temp2;
hasswapped = true;
```

At the end, print out vowel[j] next to vowelcounter[j];